# Autofac - InstancePerRequest created from DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<>() - When is it released?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, dependency-resolver

In an API controller project in .NET, there is a service I am using, say `SomeService`, requires one time only initialisation (not per request or per SomeService instance) (Although I do not think it is relevant, here the explanation for this init part: It does some setup in Azure storage for once the api is created. Doing this for every instance of `SomeService` is unnecessarely costly. Therefore there was the following line in Global.asax

```
new SomeService().Init();
```

Now, I am using `Autofac` for dependency injection. I register `SomeService` as `ISomeService` and as `InstancePerRequest` (because `SomeService` is not thread-safe). Therefore now I want to initialise SomeService in Global.asax via an instance from container. However If I try to get an instance from container as in

```
container.Resolve<ISomeService>().Init();
```

it gives this error

```
An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.
```

Therefore in Global.asax I get an instance as suggested in the error explanation.

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISomeService>().Init();
```

What I want to know is that the `SomeService` instance I get from `Current` is released or not? Since there is no real request, I am not sure. At worst I can get the instance from concrete with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to merge 2 responsibilities into 1 components which breaks the [*Single Responsibility Principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

In order to solve it, you can split the component with a component that will initialize the azure storage (`IStorageProvider` for example) and another component that will do the job. The `IStorageProvider` will be declared as `SingleInstance` (and implement `IStartable` if needed) and the other component will use this component.

```
public class AzureStorageProvider : IStorageProvider, IStartable
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // initialize storage
        this._storage = new ...
    }
} 


public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    public SomeService(IStorageProvider storageProvider) 
    { 
        this._storageProvider = storageProvider;
    }

    private readonly IStorageProvider _storageProvider; 

    public void Do()
    {
        // do things with storage
        this._storageProvider.Storage.ExecuteX(); 
    }
}
```

and the registration :

```
builder.RegisterType<AzureStorageProvider>().As<IStorageProvider>().SingleInstance(); 
builder.RegisterType<SomeService>().As<ISomeService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

you can also register a `IStorage` and let SomeService depends directly on `IStorage` and use the `IStorageProvider` as a factory.

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IStorageProvider>().Storage).As<IStorage>();
```

Comment: You have some good points. IStartable seems a good solution, however I do not want to add anything related to a specific container (like IStartable) to dll containing the services. Some can use Autofac, some use something else. Also in case I build another service for initialisation purposes and register it as singleton, its instance also will not be released. It is more by the book, I agree. However in practice nothing is changed. Am I right?

Comment: If you register the initializer as singleton, the instance will be disposed when the application stop. But I don't think it is a real problem because you won't need to dispose it, as I understand, you only need to dispose `SomeService`